# android change appearance of Spinner Button using styles

Tags: android, styles, spinner

i tried to change the style of my spinner button (not the items!). Somehow it does not get applied:

```
 <style name="myStyle"  parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dip</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
 </style>

<Spinner 
     android:id="@+id/widget_type_spinner"
     style="@style/myStyle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

on the other side if I define this in my theme it worked like a charme:

```
<style name="Standard" parent="android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/myStyle</item> 
</style>
```

But I don't want this behavior for all spinner ... 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

**In `onCreate()`**

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.widget_type_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_of_strings));
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(categorySpinnerAdapter);
```

**In your layout** (inside your layout folder)

```
<Spinner 
 android:id="@+id/widget_type_spinner"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**my_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
    android:textStyle="italic" >
</TextView>
```